# Why am I getting 'undefined' in a Javascript alert displayed after calling Python CGI script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement an ajax/python example, but when the alert is displayed the message is simply "undefined" rather than the output I should be getting according to the tutorial. Everything I've been able to find indicates the issue is because the javascript isn't getting a response back from the webserver, but I can't figure out why. I'm pretty new to Javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

HTML ('test.html')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function()
        {
            $('#clickme').click(function(){
                alert('Im going to start processing');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/scripts/py_test.py",
                    type: "post",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data: {'key':'value','key2':'value2'},
                    success: function(response){
                        alert(response.message);
                        alert(response.keys);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="clickme"> click me </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Python (scripts/py_test.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")


result = {}
result['success'] = True
result['message'] = "The command Completed Successfully"
result['keys'] = ",".join(fs.keys())

d = {}
for k in fs.keys():
d[k] = fs.getvalue(k)

result['data'] = d

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close()
```

When I run the python script from the terminal I get the following output:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
"keys": "", 
"message": "The command Completed Successfully", 
"data": {}, 
"success": true
}
```

**EDIT:**
My browser's network monitor shows I'm getting back the python script's source code.

Comment: And what does the network monitor in your browser say, what comes back from the python script?

Comment: Instead of `alert()` try to `console.log()` the entire `response` and see what you get. Also, include the `fail` callback to the jquery ajax call to see if you're getting some sort of failure error. Your console logs can be viewed if you right click the page and click "inspect" to bring up your debugger tool.

Comment: Another option would be to put `debugger` somewhere in your ajax call so that your debugger will pause in that method and allow you to view what each variable is. Try this and let us know what kind of results you get. 

I can't help you with the Python stuff sorry.

Comment: @FlorianHeer The network monitor shows I'm getting the source code from the python script back.

Comment: @df7675 because that's what you asked for.  You need a server to execute the script and return the result.  You're literally just asking the browser to get a file for you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up your web server to execute cgi. Are you running a local server or are you running off the file protocol?

Comment: @epascarello and Tibrogargan - Thanks, it looks like the issue is I need to setup the apache web server to execute python scripts. I'll try using mod_python and/or mod_wsgi and hopefully that fixes the issue.